# Where can I find sample java questions for hands-on ? Not certifications type questions

Tags: java, sample

Most google results for sample questions/problems for java, results in a link directing to mock certification questions. Does anyone know where can i find sample problems for practice ?

Thanks

Comment: You can check on
...http://www.siliconindia.com....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[codingbat](http://codingbat.com/) has hundreds of Java practice problems. In addition to sheer numbers of problems, it's also great because it has a testing mechanism in place to check if your solution is correct.

They're mostly on the easy category, but it's still good for practice, and you can always challenge yourself by imposing your own restrictions, e.g. recursion when it's not demanded, regex-only instead of traditional string manipulation, "cheating" by using libraries, etc.

Comment: thanks. the site seems to have a nice collection of problems. +1 for the suggestion to impose my own restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) is popular. There's not much point in being language-specific if your goal is general practice rather than testing detail knowledge.

Comment: thanks. interesting collection of problems.